# java install tomcat as service

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, service

I'm planning to develop an application installer which, as a part of installation, installs Apache Tomcat on Linux. Does anyone know how can I programmatically install Tomcat as service on Linux. 
Best

Answer (score 4):

If you have Tomcat installed already, you probably need to put a start up script for Tomcat in /etc/init.d

This article has a decent start up script.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3):

**Tomcat7 (Stable release 2011 January) For Debian-base:** Tested in Ubuntu 14.04.

Install Tomcat7:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-docs tomcat7-admin 
sudo apt-get install libtomcat7-java tomcat7-common tomcat7-examples
```

Start the tomcat server:

```
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

Check whether the the tomcat is running or not by access the URL http:/127.0.0.1:8080 in browser or in terminal:

```
w3m http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

[More...](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/tomcat.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a debian-base distribution, just type

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat6 tomcat6-admin tomcat6-examples
```

and you'll have a tomcat fully functional ([example for Ubuntu 10.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/tomcat.html))

Answer (score 0):

The given command will not worked for everytime on linux.

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat6 tomcat6-admin tomcat6-examples
```

I suggest to install tomcat on your linux server manually.

```
# Step 1: Install Java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y default-jdk

# Step 2: Create Tomcat User and Group
sudo groupadd tomcat
sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat

# Step 3: Download Tomcat 10
cd /opt
sudo wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.1.19/bin/apache-tomcat-10.1.19.tar.gz
sudo tar xzvf apache-tomcat-10*tar.gz
sudo mv apache-tomcat-10.1.19 tomcat

# Step 4: Update Permissions
sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /opt/tomcat/conf
sudo chmod g+x /opt/tomcat/conf
sudo chown -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/webapps/ /opt/tomcat/work/ /opt/tomcat/temp/ /opt/tomcat/logs/

# Step 5: Create a systemd Service File
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service 
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat 10 Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# Step 6: Reload systemd
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

# Step 7: Start and enable Tomcat service
sudo systemctl start tomcat
sudo systemctl enable tomcat

# Step 8: Allow port 8080 in firewall
sudo ufw allow 8080

# Step 9: Deploy WAR file
sudo cp ~/Documents/war/file.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/

# Step 10: Restart Tomcat
sudo systemctl restart tomcat

# Step 11: Verify Tomcat status
sudo systemctl status tomcat
```

The default port of tomcat server is 8080 but you can specify porton /conf/server.xml file.